# DNN Content slider module not working

Tags: slider, carousel, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 8 and i need slider for the home page. I have did extensive search about this on internet and i found `Content Slider` module.

I have added this module in the page and when i add `content slider` module a message appears in the pane like below

> No content sliders have been created yet. Please use the Actions Menu
>   to create a slider.

So i used action menu to add slider, when i click `Add Slider` option from the action menu i get the error like below image.
[Click image to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rvl4.png)

Not understanding what to do. So please any help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug related to DNN8 deprecating support for older controls. If the module is open source you should download the source code and add references to DNN8 so that you can recompile it to get the proper references.

Steps:

1. Setup your development environment ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOoQJDeTlJ0&list=PLFpEtny5sIbb9jGxJ7RBM5hIizodOCtoj&index=1))
2. Download Source Code (_source) version of the module
3. Install _Source package via the Host/Extensions page ([link](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/242/view/details/installing-the-source-version-of-a-module))
4. Open the CSProj file in Visual Studio 2015
5. Remove reference to DotNetNuke.Web
6. Add reference to DotNetNuke.Web.Deprecated (found in the website's BIN folder)
7. Compile in Release mode to package (assuming the module supports my BUILDSCRIPTS)
8. Install the created _INSTALL file to your production DNN site
9. If the module doesn't use my BUILDSCRIPTS just compile and copy the DLL generated to your production website BIN folder

Chris

Comment: So how can i do that , from where i will get reference and how i recompile it as i am getting compile time error

Comment: Thanks a lot hammond

Comment: Hey i tried with compiling _source package but can't able to compile it and i am using version 5 of wiki source code.